# $n/m\mapsto (m+n)^2+n$ is an injection

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> $n/m\mapsto (m+n)^2+n$ is an injection, where $n,m$ are positive integers, the gcd (greatest common divisor) of $m,n$ is $1$.

Oh, how to prove $(m+n)^2+n=(r+s)^2+s$ implies $n/m=s/r$, where $n,m,s,r>0, (n,m)=1=(r,s)$. What inspection?

Comment: Hint: What is $\left\lfloor \sqrt{(m+n)^2+n} \right\rfloor$?

Comment: Do we need $\gcd$ condition?

Comment: What does mean $n/m$? Is it $(n,m)\in \mathbb Z^2$?

Answer (score 1):

A parameterization of the diophantine equation $(m+n)^2+n=k$ can be given by
$$m=t^2-t-k\\n=k-t^2$$ because we have after substitution the identity
$$(-t)^2+k-t^2=k$$ It follows that if $(m+n)^2+n=(r+s)^2+s$ and $(m,n)\ne(r,s)$ then it corresponds with distinct parameters $t_1,t_2$ which gives
$$t_1^2-t_1-k=t_2^2-t_2-k\Rightarrow t_1^2-t_2^2=t_1-t_2$$ Since $t_1\ne t_2$, dividing by $t_1-t_2$ we get $$t_1+t_2=1$$ This is impossible for both, positive $t_1,t_2$. Thus $(m,n)=(r,s)$.

*Remark that for negative integers we lost the injectivity.*